# How to implement custom Checkboxes in Checkout

Tags: commerce

How can I implement custom checkboxes to drupal commerce checkout?

Those information I want to have attached to the order.

I have checked extra panes, but I haven´t found a way how to include those checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Check out one of the following modules:

1. [Commerce Checkout Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_field_group):

   > Commerce Checkout Field Group turns Commerce order field groups into checkout panes.
   >   This allows to add custom fields to the checkout pages.
2. [Commerce Fieldgroup Panes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fieldgroup_panes):

   > This module creates for each field group of the order entity a new checkout pane. These panes can be activated or deactivated as usual.
   >   This enables an easy way to collect information in the checkout process. For example customer comments, feedback about where the customer founds the shop or any other fieldable information.